# jquery plugin "jStepper" - not working for me

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use this plugin: http://jstepper.emkay.dk/Default.aspx
It increments values nicely, but when I try to launch a "onStep" event, it runs it right after the page loads, not when a value is incremented.
I hope someone can point me in the right direction, maybe a similar plugin exists? Or maybe its something simple to fix in the plugin's source.
You can try this in the "demo" box:
$(".txtTesting").jStepper({onStep:alert("test")});

Comment: You can't pass a predefined function to an object like this. Pass an anonymous function, like `onStep:function(){ alert("test") } `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to it like this.....

```
$(obj).jStepper({onStep:testfunction});

function testfunction(objTextField, bDirection, bLimitReached) {
alert("test");
}
```

or

```
 $(obj).jStepper({
      onStep: function(objTextField, bDirection, bLimitReached) {
                   alert("test");
      }
});
```

Thanks